# how to set my own message on beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

how to set my own message here, on my own language
Whatever is set as `returnValue` the resulting message is `Changes you made may not be saved.`

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event){
    if(saved == false){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = "You didn't save changes";
    }
});
```

Comment: @imvain2 - seems not possible. Is this the thru? this is 10 years ago

Comment: "seems not possible", that's exactlywhy it's a good question

Comment: @TheBombSquad - can't believe. So stupid. What can be a security risk if I write my own message. The same message I can write on any click on page. Thanks anyway

Comment: oh.. thing is.. I get your feeling but if you can customise the things.. there probably would be a way to prevent a user from ever coming off(BUT I AGREE, THEY SHOULD LET U CUSTOMISE MESSAGE >:{)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern versions of browsers removed feature of custom messages (due to security reasons, I suppose).

[Chrome from v > 51, Firefox > 4](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480)

[Safari from v > 9.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH10-SW11)

You can bind some callback, yet with no change in message in prompt.

***Edit***: found a very good documentation with compatibility graph [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

Comment: I tried `if(saved == false){console.log('not saved');...}` - doesn't work